# Fastest way to trim text in all files

Tags: c#

I have a function to trim all the text in all files in a directory. Here is the code

```
var dbtables = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(db);

foreach(var table in dbtables)
{
     string text = File.ReadAllText(table);
     File.WriteAllText(table, text.Trim());
}
```

There are many large files in this directory and it takes about 30 minutes to complete. Do you know of a faster way to do this?

Comment: This is probably more constrained by I/O to a drive than your code...

Comment: I highly doubt there is a faster way of doing this. You have to read and write the file in order to trim, so how else are you going to improve performance? Also @vcsjones makes a great point. Get an SSD :)

Comment: You should run a profiler and see where the time is being taken. It's likely in disk I/O, though you might be able to reduce the time taken by the call to `Trim()` by essentially trimming the files yourself. `Trim()` is going to be creating a new copy of what might be a very large string, so saving that copy could save you *some* time. But please profile first.

Comment: I suppose your biggest problem is that you are always writing to disk, even if `Trim` doesn't change anything. You could compare the before and after of the `Trim` to see if there is even a point in saving the file.

Comment: `grep()` is the fastest. Why do you even want a program in `C#`? Did you compare time using `Regular Expressions` with `C#`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would recommend doing for each file:

1. Read the first character.
2. If it's whitespace, you have to rewrite the whole file.

   1. Read the whole file into memory.
   2. Iterate character-by-character from the beginning to find the first non-whitespace character.
   3. Iterate character-by-character from the end to find the first non-whitespace character.
   4. Seek to the beginning of the file.
   5. Write just the middle characters of your string to the file.
   6. Set the file's length to the number of characters you wrote.
3. If the first character is not whitespace, you won't be trimming the beginning, so you can just truncate the end.

   1. Read the file backwards, character-by-character, until you hit a character that isn't whitespace.
   2. If you've found whitespace, set the file's length to its current length minus the number of whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently trims whitespace from the beginning and end of each *entire* file, rather than each line. If you want to trim whitespace on a per-line basis, you could use:

```
var dbtables = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(db);

foreach (string table in dbtables)
{
    string temp = table + ".tmp";
    using (StreamWriter target = new StreamWriter(temp))
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(table))
            target.WriteLine(line.Trim());

    File.Delete(table);
    File.Move(temp, table);
}
```

Comment: How to trim each line wasn't really his question.

Comment: To be honest, I wanted to demonstrate the benefits of using a lazily-enumerating method, such as `ReadLines`, over one which reads the entire file into memory, such as the OP’s `ReadAllText`. But then I realized that the `TrimEnd` part would not be possible to implement without having read the file in advance.